# BeautifulSoup : Weird behavior with <p>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've the following HTML content :

```
content  = """
<div>

  <div> <div>div A</div> </div>
  <p>P A</p>

  <div> <div>div B</div> </div>   
  <p> P B1</p>
  <p> P B2</p>

  <div> <div>div C</div> </div>
  <p> P C1 <div>NODE</div> </p>

</div>
"""
```

Which can be seen like that (Not sure if it helps but I like diagram) : 
[image]

If I use the following code :

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
firstDiv = soup.div
allElem = firstDiv.findAll( recursive = False)
for i, el in enumerate(allElem):
    print "element ", i , " : ", el
```

I get this :

```
element  0  :  <div> <div>div A</div> </div>
element  1  :  <p>P A</p>
element  2  :  <div> <div>div B</div> </div>
element  3  :  <p> P B1</p>
element  4  :  <p> P B2</p>
element  5  :  <div> <div>div C</div> </div>
element  6  :  <p> P C1 </p>
element  7  :  <div>NODE</div>
```

As you can see unlike elements 0, 2 or 5, the element 6 doesn't contains its children. If I change its `<p>` to `<b>` or `<div>` then it acts as excepted. Why this little difference with `<p>`  ? I'm still having that problem (if this is one?) upgrading from 4.3.2 to 4.4.6.

Comment: The final line of your html: <div>, should be </div>. Don't know if that'll somehow make a difference.

Comment: The last `</p>` is a parse error, but I don't know if BeautifulSoup handles those.

Comment: Also, why do you have a `div` as a child of a `p` in your diagram?

Comment: Try replacing `'lxml'` with `'html.parser'`. It'll give you the output you want. But I can't comment on why it isn't working with lxml.

Comment: corrected that <div>, @JoshLee this is not what it should be with :  <p> P C1 <div>NODE</div> </p> ?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar thank you it solve my problem, it also happened before with 4.3.2 when I wasn't using "lxml" yet...

Comment: @snoobdogg, as @Blender suggested, I want to retract my suggestion `Try replacing 'lxml' with 'html.parser'`. Don't try it! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`p` elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) can only contain [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) so what you have is actually invalid HTML. Here's an example of how [it's parsed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values):

> For example, a `form` element isn't allowed inside phrasing content,
>   because when parsed as HTML, a `form` element's start tag will imply a
>   `p` element's end tag. Thus, the following markup results in two
>   paragraphs, not one:
>
> ```
> <p>Welcome. <form><label>Name:</label> <input></form>
> ```
>
> It is parsed exactly like the following:
>
> ```
> <p>Welcome. </p><form><label>Name:</label> <input></form>
> ```

You can confirm that this is how browsers parse your HTML (pictured is Chrome 64):

[image: Chrome parsing invalid HTML]

`lxml` is handling this correctly, as is `html5lib`. `html.parser` doesn't implement much of the HTML5 spec and doesn't care about these quirks.

I suggest you stick to `lxml` and `html5lib` if you don't want to be frustrated in the future by these parsing differences. It's annoying when what you see in your browser's DOM inspector differs from how your code parses it.